# Bootstrap 3 re-order the layout of navbar in small screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

Currently I'm learning Bootstrap 3 and I need help with re-order the layout of navbar in small screen.
I've followed the example in [LINK](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/)

I've replaced Default / Static / Fixed with user profile
So what I want to change is when the screen is small I will have
|---------- BRAND ----------|
|[-]----------------------profile|

Here is my sample code:

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
    border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;
    margin: 0 -15px;
  }  
  .navbar-toggle {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav-user-profile .navbar-nav {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .nav-user-profile .navbar-nav>li {
    position: static;
    float: left;
  }
  .nav-user-profile .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-brand"><a href="#">Brand</a></div>
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>        
    </div>
    <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="nav-user-profile navbar-right">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

How can I achieve it?

Thanks for ideas

Comment: Show us what you have so far, then we can help.

Comment: I've updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do based on your diagram. Probably the simplest way to go is to create a div above the navbar for a second brand location. You can hide one or the other brand location with a [hidden/visible](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) class. And the profile link can be placed inside the `navbar-header` so it's visible across all viewports, it just needs to be positioned correctly on the right and the `navbar-toggle` floated to the left.

See working Snippet.

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
}
header .header-brand {
  color: #777;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
header .header-brand:focus,
header .header-brand:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5e5e5e;
}
.navbar .btn.profile-btn,
.navbar .btn.profile-btn:hover,
.navbar .btn.profile-btn:focus {
  float: right;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar .navbar-toggle {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header class="visible-xs-block"> <a class="header-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

</header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs" href="#">Brand</a>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default profile-btn">Profile</button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I want!

Comment: No problem and glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

pull-right class may help you...

or

bootstrap is divided to 12 columns for large, medium and small size

So when it breaks into small size give brand to full 12 columns using `col-sm-12` class so it will break profile to down

Answer (score 0):

I only added `text-right` very simple look where I noted with //changes*

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-brand"><a href="#">Brand</a></div>
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>        
    </div>
    <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
              //changes*
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-right">
              //changes*
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="nav-user-profile navbar-right">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```